# BLAS environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables

Using Microsoft Windows 7.0 OS and wanted to be able to call `pip` for ease of installing Python modules. I first installed `distribute`.

After running the module:

```
 pip install -U scikit-learn
```

I realized that I need to set the BLAS environment variable. I do not fully understand what this entails, i.e. what should it be set to?  set `BLAS="something"`

(Note: I also skipped this and tried: `easy_install -U scikit-learn`, which seemed to work fine. But when I attempt to import the module in iPython it doesn't recognize it, it gives "invalid syntax" pointing to "-").

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: You wouldn't import `scikit-learn` in Python, as that is not a valid module identifier - as the error states, you can't have hyphens in names. You'll have to look at the documentation to see what the actual modules are called. But it sounds like your easy_install worked.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks, you're absolutely correct. For others who may be interested, the short name of the module that you want to import is 'sklearn'.